# What is the difference between sommerfield number and bearing characteristic number in bearing design?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, bearings, machine-elements

After reading a few texts on the topic of sliding contact bearings I am confused between the bearing characteristic number and the sommerfield number.

As per J.E shigley's text both bearing characteristic number and sommerfield number are same and is given as[image]

But as per V.B bhandari,R.S khurmi texts the bearing characteristic number and sommerfield number are different and is given as[image][image]

then again in Wikipedia I have seen that they too followed the shigley's text definition with an additional number called Hersey number given as[image]

Comment: Hersey number could be the american equivalent.

Comment: Alot of time with these numbers is how they are used i.e. they are tools, you might find a table  that interests you and inorder to read off a value you need one definition as opposed to the other. Or in another case it maybe a design rule you want to follow. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon your inquiry when I was curious about the same thing.

But contribution (as of now, but still learning) is that the Sommerfeld number implies you are working with a journal type bearing (with a radial component). But the Hersey number is more ubiquitous, and can be used for other bearing types (like for example, thrust bearings).

Hope there are more comments to help clarify or confirm what I am interpreting as the difference between the Sommerfeld number and the Hersey number.